# Why does the Informatica session not proceed with deletion of data?

Tags: oracle, etl, informatica-powercenter

I have a flat-file source where the first column is used to flag a record for insert, delete or update. Deletion/Updation is done based on the PK in the target table.

So we have the records flow from the source into the router where it gets redirected to a Update strategy transformation - one each for Insert, update and delete operation.

I have done an update override for the delete and update target instances.

> *In the workflow, I have set the session properties as follows:*
>
> 1. For the target that handles the inserts, I checked 'Insert' in the target's session properties.
> 2. For the target that handles the updates, I checked 'Update as Update' in the target's session properties.
> 3. For the target that handles the deletion, I checked 'Delete' in the target's session properties.

Now the session works fine when all rows are inserts. But when there is a single update or delete the session just doesn't proceed after fetching the source data..

Not sure what is causing such behavior.. Any ideas on how to resolve or further debug this..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the workflow session to treat source rows as 'Data driven'.
When you create a session from a mapping wich already have an 'Update Strategy' this is set automatically but if you add an 'Update Strategy' to the mapping after the session is created you must change this yourself.